# Naming convention for fields/variables of type slice

Tags: go, naming-conventions

What should the name of a variable or struct field be for a slice of int IDs?

For example, a struct with a list of user-ids of type []int:

```
type Result struct {
  UserIDs []int
}
```

Or without trailing **s**:

```
type Result struct {
  UserID []int
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name should describe the content of the variable. The content of your field is multiple user IDs, so name it `UserIDs`. `UserID` describes a single user ID.

Using the plural form also makes it convenient to loop over the slice and use the singular form for the loop variable, e.g.:

```
for _, userID := range result.UserIDs {
    // Do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of go libraries go as far as creating type aliases for slices of types, e.g.

```golang
type Tokens = []Token
```

With this in mind I'd say `UserIDs` would be the correct naming convention

Comment: This is bad practice and basically a missuse of type aliases.

Comment: "A lot of go libraries go as far as creating type aliases for slices of types" -- Really? Can you point to some examples? This would be a really bad idea, so I'd be surprised if it's widely used.

Answer (score -1):

It depends.

If `[]int` represents a single user ID, which is composed of multiple `int`s, then `UserID` is the proper name.

If `[]int` represents multiple user IDs, each of which is represented by a single `int`, then `UserIDs` is the proper name.

There's no special logic here. There's nothing related to Go here. It's just the English language.

Comment: Good point. I had the latter case in mind.